# How to work with external JS file in Signal r

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, signalr, signalr.client

I have the following signal r client code on my razor partial view
It is working fine in partial view. I want to move it to an external javascript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            debugger;
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
            var proxy = $.connection.broadcastMessage;

            proxy.client.receiveNotification = function (message, count) {
                debugger;
                $("#not_count").html(count);
                $("#not_count").show();
       };
  $.connection.hub.start();
});
</script>
```

How can i move this to an external JS file?

Comment: So what's the problem just to cut this code from the view, paste into some external file and then include this file as `<script src = "path_to_the_file"></script>`?

Answer (score 0):

Add new javascript file(eg. signalrStuff.js) to solution with your code:

```
$(function () { debugger; $.connection.hub.logging = true; var proxy = $.connection.broadcastMessage;

            proxy.client.receiveNotification = function (message, count) {
                debugger;
                $("#not_count").html(count);
                $("#not_count").show();
       };
  $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

Then reference the new script replacing the javascript in the partial view:

```
<script src="signalrStuff.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure to load the jQuery script first.